# Black screen, won't sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

While I'm using it, my laptop screen suddenly goes black, and the machine won't sleep from power button or shutting the lid. `ctrl-alt-del` has no visible effect, nor do other keyboard inputs. (e.g., pressing the mute button doesn't light up the indicator, though it remains lit if it was) Restarting usually solves the problem, otherwise I just restart until it does.

Specs:
Model: HP Notebook 15-dy1751ms
OS: Windows 10 Home 64-bit 21H2
OS build: 19044.1706

Comment: Anything in the Windows Event Logs?

Comment: Update BIOS, Power Driver and Video Driver and see if that helps. Make sure the battery is charging properly.

Comment: @John I don't think it's video, since it also doesn't sleep. Anyway, Windows Update says everything is up to date. When it's working normally & I can read the battery indicator it looks like the charging is normal. This happened when the battery was nowhere near empty, though my PC sometimes randomly hibernates with plenty of power left, so it's very possible that I have power problems.

Comment: Maybe (for a couple of weeks) turn both Hibernation and Hybrid Sleep OFF and just use regular Sleep. I suggested Video because the screen went black - it would not hurt to update it.

Comment: If you think Power problems on a laptop you probably need to get it serviced either by HP or by a local computer shop.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik what section, &c.?

Comment: To search *all8 the many Event logs at once by time (i.e., when the black screen occurred), use a tool such as Nirsoft's free *FullEventLogView*, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html , in *Advanced Options* (F9).